# Duplicated execution plan for Query on the Azure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a query and run it using SQL management studio. Usually, there is created one execution plan for a query in the studio. But sometimes I can catch up the duplicated execution plans for a single Query on the Azure SQL like below.
[image]

When I open the query from this plan I see the duplicated query. As if the copied query is pasted into the same query. The same in Query 1 and Query 2. See below.
[image]

Maybe someone knows why does this happen and how to avoid this behavior? How is that even possible?

P.S. Time of execution query was increased from 2 sec to 20 sec and more.

P.P.S. The warning in the Query 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the queries were ran with different settings. I can notice that one has a warning and the other doesn't.

Reference:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2014/04/03/i-think-i-am-getting-duplicate-query-plan-entries-in-sql-servers-procedure-cache/